Problem with a javascripit function that reads a dat file when incorporated into html
I am trying to incorporate a javascript function that takes some dates from a dat files into a notification alert I have on a html page, I tried the function on a javascript enviroment and worked just fine, but when I try to execute in my html page is keeps failing. I don't understand why.
function dayoftheweek(){
    date =new Date(reikai_y,reikai_m-1,reikai_d);
    currentDayOfWeek = YOUBI[date.getDay()];
} 

today = y + m + d; // 20151107


///function to get date directly from schedule
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');
var reiday
var reimonth
var reiyear
var reikailist

function readschedule(){
    // File path (adjust the path as necessary)
    const filePath = path.join('..', 'schedule', 'schedule.dat');

    // Create a Readable stream from the file
    const fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');

    // Create an interface to read lines from the stream
    const lines = fileData.split(/\r?\n/);
    var linelist

    reikailist=""

   // Process each line
    lines.forEach(line => {
        const linelist = line.split("######");
        dayreikai(linelist[0]);
        reikailist += reiyear + reimonth + reiday + ":";
    });

    // Remove the trailing colon
    reikailist = reikailist.slice(0, -9);
    return reikailist
}

I just try and paste it, I had other javascript function on the same script block and they are working, but the readschedule specifically does not work. I would like to know the reason and possible solution so I can implement it.

const fs = require('fs'); is only used in node.js, you can't use it in html.

perhaps have a look at express or File Reader

There’s node.js script all over what you posted so I don’t believe that this script is intended for a website and that you simply forgot to add the right tags to your post or maybe you just didn’t realize that this script isn't suitable for websites!
Anyway, this looks more like a client side NW or Electron project (snippets?) but...
You’ve got lots of badly declared identifiers in the middle of nowhere and lots of missing semicolons such as...
var reiday
var reimonth
var reiyear
var reikailist

And further down...
var linelist

    reikailist=""

It’s good practice to always initialize your identifiers, separate them with commas, and add the semi colon/s at the end like this...
var linelist=0, reikailist="";

Even one of your comments is dodgy with 3 slashes in a row!
///function to get date directly from schedule

I get the impression you’re just cutting and pasting snippets here and there without really understanding what the code does so it’s pretty hard to help someone in such cases. :(
@Pluto
Not all HTML is published on the Internet... these days you can run HTML (with or without node.js) client side, so your statement is incorrect.
